# xtype: filefield not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

i had a popup that looks like this :

```
items : [{

    xtype: 'form',
    title: 'Upload a Photo',
    width: 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    frame: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'photo',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
    }]
}]
```

i only copied the example in sencha docs but when i run it, it gives me this :

[image]

instead of this :

[image]

my concern is that the button 'choose file' displayed instead of 'select photo'

how can i solve this.. ?

Comment: Looks like you've got some kind of CSS conflict, there's several elements in the comparison that don't match up. The font size on the header, the panel background colour.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you test IE9, IE10 and Chrome?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli header font and panel background was set by me (custom theme).@ChristophHartmann i am using chrome and IE 9, btw, i updated my images (i only have to set frame: true), still the problem occurs

Comment: why do you have a renderTo: Ext.getBody() ? Can you comment it out and try again?

Comment: facing same problem, any solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem... As @evan-trimboli mentioned, it was a css conflict. Just run `sencha app build` command for your project and it will work fine..

`Help yourself by helping others`

Answer (score 0):

I would add that run sencha app build, and then clear CACHE in browser.